# Udev Rules Not Running

Tags: udev, devices, hardware, block-device, usb-device

I'm playing with Udev Rules on OpenSuse Leap, and I'm trying to run a simple and small script once a USB device is plugged into my system.

However, my script which I added in my keyword "RUN+=" does not run.

These are the steps a follow:

1) I wrote the rule "**10_MY_RULES.rules**" based on the info given by **udevadm info**.

```
KERNEL=="sdf1", SUBSYSTEM=="block", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{product}=="Flash Drive", ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Samsung",ATTRS{idProduct}=="1000", ATTRS{idVendor}=="090C", RUN="/home/user/bin/script.sh"
```

My script "**script.sh**" is the follwoing:

```
#!/bin/bash; mkdir /home/user/Desktop/CREATE_FOLDER_TEST
```

2) OpenSuse Leap has several places where it allocates udev rules.

These are the locations:

- /etc/udev/rules.d
- /usr/lib/udev/rules.d
- /run/udev/rules.d

I put my rule in "**/run/udev/rules.d**" given that when I plug my USB device **udev** will create an access file under **/run**.

3) I run the following commands:

- udevadm control --reload-rules
- udevadm trigger

4) Once that was done I also run "**udevadm monitor**" to see what my system was doing once a peripheral device plugged in, in this case, my USB.

5) I notice no action was being performed, my script was not running, when my flash drive was being added to the system. So I ran the following command to trigger my rule on the specific device

- udevadm test --action=add /path/to/device

I noticed my rule was being read as you can see in the last line of my picture ...

[image]

Without any luck, I revised my rule and tinker with it. I add more **KERNELS, SUBSYSTEMS,ATTRS,etc**

All of the above I ran in two modes as **Root** and **User**.

Comment: Have you tried only using `SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"` instead of two `SUBSYSTEMS`?

Comment: I agree with @slybloty, simply use `SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"`. For USB redirection we have a rule like this:
`KERNEL=="[0-9]-[0-9]", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", RUN="/usr/local/bin/usb_share"` 

If that doesn't work I would reduce the number of checks to a minimum, then start increasing them step by step if the rule still is applied.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to execute your `script.sh` manually?

I tried, and got

```
bash: ./script.sh: /bin/bash;: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

You can't use a semi-colon as a command separator on the `#!` line of the script. That line is only for specifying the script interpreter and possibly options for it, nothing else.

As it is, your rule seems to fail because your `script.sh` fails to execute; your udev rules might be just fine. As @eblock commented, you should use the minimum necessary number of checks: if your rule isn't working, you should remove some checks, not add more.

Also note that `/run` is not persistent, as it is located on a tmpfs filesystem (= essentially a RAM disk). Anything you put in there will be gone after next reboot. As a result, `/run/udev/rules.d` should be used only for auto-generated rules that are produced by other rules or some other automation.

`/usr/lib/udev/rules.d` is for the distribution's standard rules. The system administrator is supposed to use `/etc/udev/rules.d` to supplement or override the standard rules as necessary.